# MySQL delete "inactive" rows

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I've got 2 tables:

#### user

id | name | mail | pass | salt

#### entries

id | uid | title | text | timestamp

Now I want to delete all rows of `entries` with an `uid`, which doesn't exist in `user`-table
(deleted users)

I think this might work like this:

```
DELETE entries FROM user, entries WHERE [What comes here? I don't know :(]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM entries WHERE uid NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM user);
```

Comment: Why "SELECT *DISTINCT* id..."?

Comment: @Catcall: Well, theoretically, there really shouldn't be repeated `id` values in the table, so it doesn't really matter. But for general `DELETE FROM ... WHERE ... NOT IN ...` kinds of queries, this will shorten the list of values that need to be matched for the `WHERE` clause by removing duplicated values.

Comment: I was under the impression that `NOT EXISTS ()` created better plans than `NOT IN ()` in MySQL?

Comment: @Dems: I haven't done a ton of research on it, but doing a quick Google search led me to a page with some research and in the summary it says "That’s why the best way to search for missing values in MySQL is using a LEFT JOIN / IS NULL or NOT IN rather than NOT EXISTS." - http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/

Comment: Thankyou, this works. But `DISTINCT` is unnecessary, because `id` is a primary key